# Creating separate dxf file for each ArcSDE featureclass with FME 2017?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form, feature-class, dxf

I am having problems creating separate dxf files for my sde Featureclasses with fme2017. I am not a CAD user but have to export over 200 featureclasses out of my 10.3.1 SDE Database. I have created the sde reader which splits the database into the featureclasses and would now like to create a separate dxf for each individual featureclass. Because I have over 200 I want to do this automatically. I have already tried using a featureclassfilter but the output is always a single dxf. If I have tried using a generic writer or  fan-out with featuretype as parameter it still routes all to the same single dxf.

How can I create one dxf for each Featureclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fanout should be the solution. I just created a movie to demo the technique.

It's online here: https://www.screencast.com/t/FfD5z5Yw5

(Sorry, my microphone must be a bit sensitive. It sounds like I am hammering the keyboard. I'm not.)